# sound designers: Expectation vs reality?

Tags: experiences, sound-designer, questionnaire

Hello fellow sound designers,

I would like to propose these questions to you all. I'm asking these questions because I am writing a report on sound designers in the industry. I'm hoping to find out what the difference is between what we expect and the reality of the job market at the moment? I really appreciate any form of response.

•   Do you find that sound related jobs in the industry are difficult to obtain?

•   How much experience is required before realistically becoming a freelance sound designer?

•   Does the industry seem to be on the decline, are there jobs available?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi josh - this question is extraordinarily subjective, location based and time bound. While I think your second point may have value as a separate question, the others don't really fit in a Stack Exchange model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

• Do you find that sound related jobs in the industry are difficult to obtain?

Yes, because everyone wants a media/entertainment job. And sound generally is the smallest group in any production team.

• How much experience is required before realistically becoming a freelance sound designer?

As much as is needed to make someone interested about your sound.

• Does the industry seem to be on the decline, are there jobs available?

It's a very volatile industry, because it's dependent on the consumption of media. The better (in terms of products and consumer base) company or group you work with, the more stable it'll be. But this (stability) is obviously also the biggest source of competition. Because everyone would like stability.

Consider freelancing, if you enjoy your work and want to control your work, but don't want to delve into the (extreme) competitiveness about the very limited positions and bad job security of media work.